# Code first migration issue, error occuring AFTER update-database

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

My code first migrations usually work flawlessly.

Usually, I can just type  `Update-Database -Verbose` and the database migrates flawlessly. Sometimes, that will give me a problem and I need to type `Update-Database -TargetMigration:0`.

However, sometimes when changing columns in Identity like adding a custom field, I then try to update database. It goes through just fine, but then when I go to run the code, it gives me the pesky `"consider using code first migrations...."` error as if I didn't even update the database, the only way around this that I have found is installing a clean SQL instance...

I know surely there must be a way to make this happen the right way.

Comment: when you roll back to migration 0, then do you update the db before launching the app?

Comment: Yes. I am doing exactly that.